# Rx Network Polling & Immediately getting first result

Tags: retrofit, rx-java

I want to poll a service from my application, so I can refresh the data periodically (~15 minutes). However, this same data will also be needed on startup. I'm using Retrofit & RxAndroid.

I can easily get the network data immediately (or whenever the call returns, rather), and I have been working on doing a repeating call like this:

```
    return mNetworker.getInitializationProperites(deviceId)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io()) // database i/o will need done
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .delay(20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // 20 seconds for testing
            .repeat()
            .subscribe(onNext, RxErrorHandler.handle(), onComplete);
```

This method (and others using `timer` and `interval`) get the time interval correct, but deliver the result late. Particularly, in the above, I know the webservice is hit immediately, yet it then waits 20 seconds to actually emit the result.

Is there a way I can combine the ideas of getting first result ASAP & also schedule itself to repeat indefinitely? My other thought is to create two different observables and subscribe to them separately, but it seems like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of starting with the network observable and repeating it, you could start with a `timer` Observable and `flatMap` it with the network observable, something like

```
Observable.timer(0L, 20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS).flatMap(i -> doNetworkRequest())
```

Comment: Dammit, I can't believe I missed that version of `timer`. It was staring me in the face the whole time. [Docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#timer%28long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) for those interested.